# Trying to setState with React Hooks, using axios.. Not getting data

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm using an axios call to a database to get "about me" data, for client to update. DB is connected properly, as I am able to log in just fine, I've isolated this issue pretty well to my GET request.

My context provider file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export const UserContext = React.createContext()
const userAxios = axios.create()

userAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    return config
})

const UserProvider = (props) => {
    const initState = {
        user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || {},
        token: localStorage.getItem("token") || "",
        authErrMsg: ""
    }
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initState)

    const [dataState, setDataState] = useState({
        bioData: []
    })

    const login = credentials => {
        axios.post("/auth/login", credentials)
            .then(res => {
                const { user, token } = res.data
                localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user))
                localStorage.setItem("token", token)
                setUserState(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => handleAuthErr(err.response.data.errMsg))
    }

    const handleAuthErr = errMsg => {
        setUserState(prevUserState => ({
            ...prevUserState,
            authErrMsg: errMsg
        }))
    }

    const logout = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem("token")
        localStorage.removeItem("user")
        setUserState({
            user: {},
            token: "",
            authErrMsg: ""
        })
    }

    const getData = () => {
        axios.get('/info/bio')
            .then(res => {
                setDataState(prevData => ({
                    ...prevData,
                    bioData: res.data
                }))
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    

    const deleteBio = (id) => {
        userAxios.delete(`/api/bio/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                setDataState(prevData => ({
                    ...prevData,
                    bioData: dataState.bioData.filter(bio => bio._id !== id)
                }))
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.errMsg))
    }

    
    const addBio = (newText) => {
        const newBio = {
            bioText: newText
        }
        userAxios.post('/api/bio', newBio)
            .then(res => {
                getData()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const editBio = (update, id) => {
        const updatedBio = {
            bioText: update
        }
        userAxios.put(`/api/bio/${id}`, updatedBio)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data, 'edited')
            getData()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider
            value={{
                user: userState.user,
                token: userState.token,
                authErrMsg: userState.authErrMsg,
                login: login,
                logout: logout,
                getData: getData,
                dataState: dataState,
                editBio: editBio,
                deleteBio: deleteBio,
                addBio: addBio
            }}>
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserProvider
```

Here's my Bio component. The loading effect never changes because for some reason, no "bioData" is saving, in the provider. Tested it with that little button/handleClick and coming up an empty array.

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { UserContext } from './context/userProvider'

const Bio = () => {
    const { token, editBio, dataState: {bioData} } = useContext(UserContext)
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState('Loading')

    useEffect(() => {
        if(bioData[0]?._id === undefined){
            setLoader('Loading')
        }else {
            setLoader(bioData[0]?._id)
        }
    })

    // let initText = bioData[0].bioText
    const [bioText, setBioText] = useState("initText")

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setBioText(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleUpdate = () => {
        editBio(bioText, bioData[0]._id)
        alert`Bio successfully updated. :)`
    }
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(bioData)
    }

    return (
        <div className='bio'>
            <h1>About Me</h1>
            <div className='bio-content'>
                {loader === 'Loading' ?
                    <div>
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                        <button onClick={handleClick}>thing</button>
                    </div>
                    :
                    <>
                        {token ? 
                        <div className="editBio">
                            <p>edit mee</p>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <h4>{bioData[0].bioText}</h4> }
                    </>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Bio
```

Thanks in advance guys! Let me know if I can post routes or anything that might be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to put this code on codesandbox with barebone functionality?

Comment: when is `getData` called?

Comment: Ah, @thedude. It's always something super simple. I wasn't calling `getData` in my component. I've called it with a `useEffect` hook in `Bio` and it's working now. Thanks a bunch. Still trying to solidify my React knowledge and it's usually something small.